# VueJS, Apollo, Rails - Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, graphql-ruby

Here is my setup

```
const token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      'authenticity_token': token,
    }
  }
});
```

I'm trying both `X-CSRF-Token` and `authenticity_token` and in my GQL request I can see that it's properly being added to the header. I'm grabbing this off of Rail's `= csrf_meta_tags` and the value is not null or undefined.

I keep getting a 422 `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.` from the rails server.

Answer (score 3):

you can try reading the CSRF token this way:
    `document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')`

as far as I know, you cannot use the `$` jQuery selector here.
Also, `'X-CSRF-TOKEN'` is working on my side

Comment: According to the OP, the token is read properly and sent to the server. Why should it be impossible to use `$` here anyways?

Comment: right, sorry, I think I didn't require the needed thins when I was trying